# After migrating ejabberd verison 20.04 to 23.04 facing function match cause issue in ejabberd route IQ

Tags: ejabberd, ejabberd-module

we are using the privacy and ping modules in Ejabberd, After migrate our Ejabberd verison from 20.07 to 23.04,  we are getting the Module failed to handle the query in ejabberd_route IQ

Try this below IQ in PSI +

<iq type="get" id="aad6a">

<query xmlns="jabber:iq:privacy"/>

</iq>

I am getting the below error in ejabberd same issue happen in mod *ping and mod mix* pam module

```
2023-03-21 12:44:21.820818+05:30 [error] <0.1269.0>@gen_iq_handler:process_iq/4:116 Failed to process iq:
#iq{id = <<"aad6a">>,type = get,lang = <<"en">>,
    from = #jid{user = <<"userid">>,server = <<"localhost">>,
                resource = <<"Mobile-123">>,luser = <<"userid">>,
                lserver = <<"localhost">>,lresource = <<"Mobile-123">>},
    from_jid = undefined,
    to = #jid{user = <<"userid">>,server = <<"localhost">>,
              resource = <<>>,luser = <<"userid">>,
              lserver = <<"localhost">>,lresource = <<>>},
    sub_els = [#xmlel{name = <<"query">>,
                      attrs = [{<<"xmlns">>,<<"jabber:iq:privacy">>}],
                      children = []}],
    meta = #{ip => {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1}}}
** exception error: no function clause matching 
                  mod_privacy:process_iq({iq,<<"aad6a">>,get,<<"en">>,
                                          {jid,<<"userid">>,
                                           <<"localhost">>,<<"Mobile-123">>,
                                           <<"userid">>,<<"localhost">>,
                                           <<"Mobile-123">>},
                                          undefined,
                                          {jid,<<"userid">>,
                                           <<"localhost">>,<<>>,
                                           <<"userid">>,<<"localhost">>,
                                           <<>>},
                                          [{privacy_query,[],undefined,
                                            undefined}],
                                          #{ip => {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1}}}) (src/mod_privacy.erl, line 126)
   in function  gen_iq_handler:process_iq/3 (src/gen_iq_handler.erl, line 131)
   in call from gen_iq_handler:process_iq/4 (src/gen_iq_handler.erl, line 109)
   in call from ejabberd_sm:route/1 (src/ejabberd_sm.erl, line 146)
   in call from ejabberd_router:do_route/1 (src/ejabberd_router.erl, line 399)
   in call from ejabberd_router:route/1 (src/ejabberd_router.erl, line 92)
   in call from ejabberd_c2s:check_privacy_then_route/2 (src/ejabberd_c2s.erl, line 874)
   in call from xmpp_stream_in:process_authenticated_packet/2 (src/xmpp_stream_in.erl, line 727)
```

Comment: ejabberd 23.04 was not released, how did you install it?

I installed ejabberd 23.01, registered an account, logged in, and sent the IQ you showed: it returns correctly. Try with a new account. Try installing a small ejabberd with default config in another machine, does it work then?

Comment: Sorry, It's my mistake, but Packet#message.body is shows empty when I try the below command<message type="chat" to="username@localhost" id="b1bcff1c98824bc5963cf5ffb89bb104"
              xml:lang='en'>
     <body>Art thou not Romeo, and a Montague?</body>
  </message>

Comment: You make a question in the post, and a different question in a comment. This is confusing. If the first question is solved, close it and open a new question explaining it completely: what ejabberd version, what configuration, what modifications you make to the source code, and how to reproduce the problem.